# Link to record === Instead of displaying a text (String)

Tags: aura, datatable

I'm trying to add a datatable component to a flow in order to display knowledge articles.
I've downloaded the component online. Unfortunately the component doesn't give me the possibility to access my article thru my datatable, it just displays the Article title as a String.

[image]

I was wondering how I can change the title instead of displaying a string I'd like to display the title as a link so when a user clicks on it, it will redirect him to the record page.

Here's my lightning component:

```
<aura:component implements="lightning:availableForFlowScreens">

    <aura:attribute name="obj" type="String" />
    <aura:attribute name="mydata" type="SObject[]"/>
    <aura:attribute name="saveMydata" type="SObject[]"/>
    <aura:attribute name="selectedRows" type="SObject[]"/>
    <aura:attribute name="sortedBy" type="String" />
    <aura:attribute name="sortedDirection" type="String" />
    <aura:attribute name="maxRowSelection" type="String" />
    <aura:attribute name="hideCheckboxColumn" type="Boolean" default="false" />
    <aura:attribute name="preSelection" type="SObject[]" />
    <aura:attribute name="preSelectedIds" type="List" />

    <!-- CHANGE THE OBJECT NAMES HERE AND IN THE DESIGN FILE TO SUPPORT DIFFERENT OBJECTS -->
        <aura:attribute name="mydata_standard1" type="Knowledge__kav[]"/>
        <aura:attribute name="selectedRows_standard1" type="Knowledge__kav[]"/>

    
    <aura:attribute name="mycolumns" type="List"/>
    
    <aura:attribute name="column01_icon" type="String"/>
    <aura:attribute name="column01_label" type="String"/>
    <aura:attribute name="column01_fieldName" type="String"/>
    <aura:attribute name="column01_type" type="String" default="text"/>
    <aura:attribute name="column01_width" type="Integer"/>
    <aura:attribute name="column01_align" type="String"/>
    <aura:attribute name="column01_editable" type="Boolean" default="false"/>

    
    <aura:attribute name="singleSelection" type="String" />
    <aura:attribute name="hideShow" type="String" default="show"/>

    <aura:attribute name="keyField" type="String" default="Id"/>
    <aura:attribute name="showButtons" type="Boolean" default="false"/>

    <aura:handler name="init" value="{! this }" action="{! c.init }"/>
    
    <aura:if isTrue="{! v.showButtons}" >
        <lightning:datatable aura:id="flowTable" data="{! v.mydata }" 
            columns="{! v.mycolumns }" 
            keyField="{! v.keyField }"
            sortedBy="{! v.sortedBy }"
            sortedDirection="{! v.sortedDirection }"
            maxRowSelection="{! v.maxRowSelection }"
            selectedRows="{! v.preSelectedIds }"                 
            onrowselection="{! c.getSelectedName }"
            hideCheckboxColumn="{! v.hideCheckboxColumn }"
            onsort="{! c.updateColumnSorting }"
            onsave="{! c.handleSave }"
            oncancel="{! c.cancelChanges }"/>
        <aura:set attribute="else">
            <lightning:datatable aura:id="flowTable" data="{! v.mydata }" 
                columns="{! v.mycolumns }" 
                keyField="{! v.keyField }"
                sortedBy="{! v.sortedBy }"
                sortedDirection="{! v.sortedDirection }"
                maxRowSelection="{! v.maxRowSelection }"
                selectedRows="{! v.preSelectedIds }"                 
                onrowselection="{! c.getSelectedName }"
                hideCheckboxColumn="{! v.hideCheckboxColumn }"
                onsort="{! c.updateColumnSorting }"
                suppressBottomBar="true"
                oncellchange="{! c.handleSave }"/>
        </aura:set>
    </aura:if>
</aura:component>
```

here's my Controller:

```
({
    init: function (cmp, event, helper) {
        
        // Maximum Row Selection
        if(cmp.get('v.singleSelection') == '1') {
            cmp.set('v.maxRowSelection','1')
        }
        
        // Hide Checkbox Column
        if(cmp.get('v.hideShow').toLowerCase() == 'hide') {
            cmp.set('v.hideCheckboxColumn', true)
        }

        // Column Settings
        var cols = new Array();
        for (var i=101; i < 111; i++) {
            var varIcon = ''            
            if(cmp.get('v.column'+i.toString().substring(1)+'_fieldName')) {
                if (i.toString().substring(1) === '01') {
                    varIcon = cmp.get('v.column'+i.toString().substring(1)+'_icon')
                }
                console.log(i);  
                var cellClass =  
                    cmp.get('v.column'+i.toString().substring(1)+'_type').toLowerCase() == 'number' ||
                    cmp.get('v.column'+i.toString().substring(1)+'_type').toLowerCase() == 'currency'
                    ? 
                    {
                        fieldName : cmp.get('v.column'+i.toString().substring(1)+'_fieldName') + 'class'
                    }
                    :
                    {};
                    
                var vEditable = (cmp.get('v.column'+i.toString().substring(1)+'_editable') == true);
                                             
                cols.push({
                    iconName: varIcon,
                    label: cmp.get('v.column'+i.toString().substring(1)+'_label'), 
                    fieldName: cmp.get('v.column'+i.toString().substring(1)+'_fieldName'), 
                    type: cmp.get('v.column'+i.toString().substring(1)+'_type'), 
                    sortable: true, 
                    initialWidth: cmp.get('v.column'+i.toString().substring(1)+'_width'), 
                    cellAttributes: {
                        alignment: cmp.get('v.column'+i.toString().substring(1)+'_align'),
                        class: cellClass                            
                    },
                    editable: vEditable
                });                                   
            }
        }

        cmp.set('v.mycolumns', cols);

        // Object Selection
        if(cmp.get('v.mydata_standard1') && cmp.get('v.mydata_standard1').length > 0){
            cmp.set('v.mydata', cmp.get('v.mydata_standard1'));
            
            cmp.set('v.obj', 'standard1');
            cmp.set('v.preSelection', cmp.get('v.selectedRows_standard1'));
        }

        console.log('Init - ',cmp.get('v.mydata'));
        
        // Pre-selected Rows
        var rows = cmp.get('v.preSelection');
        var list = [];
        for (var i=0, len = rows.length; i < len; i++) {
            list.push(rows[i].Id);
        }
        cmp.set('v.preSelectedIds', list);

        // Save pre-edit data
        cmp.set('v.saveMydata', cmp.get('v.mydata'));
    },

    // Return Selected Table Rows
    getSelectedName: function (cmp, event) {
        //save the selected rows into a flow-accessible attribute
        var selectedRows = event.getParam('selectedRows');
        var obj = cmp.get('v.obj');
        if(obj == 'standard1'){
            cmp.set("v.selectedRows_standard1", selectedRows);    
        }
      

    },

    // Client-side controller called by the onsort event handler
    updateColumnSorting: function (cmp, event, helper) {
        var fieldName = event.getParam('fieldName');
        var sortDirection = event.getParam('sortDirection');
        // assign the latest attribute with the sorted column fieldName and sorted direction
        cmp.set("v.sortedBy", fieldName);
        cmp.set("v.sortedDirection", sortDirection);
        helper.sortData(cmp, fieldName, sortDirection);
    },

    handleSave: function(cmp, event, helper) {
        helper.updateEditedValues(cmp, event.getParam('draftValues'));
        if(cmp.get('v.showButtons')) {
            // Clear Buttons from the Table
            cmp.find('flowTable').set('v.draftValues', null);
            // Save current table data values
            cmp.set('v.saveMydata', cmp.get('v.mydata'));
        }
    },

    cancelChanges: function (cmp, event, helper) {
        // Clear Buttons from the Table
        cmp.find('flowTable').set('v.draftValues', null);
        // Replace current table data values with the saved values
        cmp.set('v.mydata', cmp.get('v.saveMydata'));
    },    
    
})
```

Comment: Keep in mind that if you make it a link, you'll have to also toggle the data type back and forth for edit mode in order to be able to edit the name.

Comment: Hi @sfdcfox, 
Thanks for your comment.
Do you know how i can do this?

Comment: Btw, there's no need to edit the data

Comment: Without knowing the underlying structure of the data, I'd have to take a few guesses, but generally speaking, check if you're on the Title field, and if so, use a field `type` of `url` and include a `typeAttributes` property to specify the `label` attribute, then transform the `fieldName` value to the URL to navigate to.